# If $m,n$ are integers $\gt 2$ then $R(m,n) \leq R(m-1,n)+R(m,n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

THIS IS NOT THE DUPLICATE OF ABOVE BECAUSE:I require pigeonhole principle argument to my doubt which is not stated in the answer to above question...

I missed my lecture the day the following theorem for ramsey numbers was proved in the class:

**If $m,n$ are integers $\gt 2$ then $R(m,n) \leq R(m-1,n)+R(m,n-1)$**

*Proof*:

> $R(m,n)=$ smallest possible size of group of persons s.t. among these either $\exists \,m$ persons mutual friends or $\exists \,n$ mutual enemies.
>
> Let $p=R(m-1,n)\,,q=R(m,n-1)$ and $r=p+q$.
> Consider the group $\{1,2\ldots,r\}$ of $r$ persons.
>
> Let L=$\{$set of persons friends with '$1$'$\}$ and M=$\{$set of persons enemies with '$1$'$\}$
>
> Then $L\cap M=\phi$ .So, we have $|L|+|M|=|L\cup M|=r-1=p+q-1$
>
> We cannot have $|L|\leq p-1$ and $|M|\leq q-1$ .
>
> $\therefore$ either $|L| \geq p$ or $|M|\geq q$.

This the starting paragraph of the proof which I have stated above. and later the proof is divided into two cases ,(1. when $L$ has atleast $p$ elements. 2.when $M$ has atleast $q$ elements),which I understood...

But what I can't understand is the step at begining of proof that:

> We cannot have $|L|\leq p-1$ and $|M|\leq q-1$ .
>
> $\therefore$ either $|L| \geq p$ or $|M|\geq q$.

The above statement makes **the use of pigeonhole principle** but I don't know how.Please anyone who can help me with this ,as I have no idea for this.....

Comment: @spectraa Yes, it does.